# laravel migrate:rollback wrong

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel version 5.1.43(LTS)

I use `php artisan migrate:rollback` in terminal then return error messages. But the database is changed. Then I re-entered this command again there is no error messages.

Can anybody help me fix this problem?

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP'user_id'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `crm_user` drop index `user_id`)
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'user_id'; check that column/key exists

My migration code

```
public function down()
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn('crm_user', 'user_id')) {
        Schema::table('crm_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('user_id');
            $table->dropIndex('user_id');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your index is dropped automatically when you drop your column. So then when you try to drop the index separately, you get the error that it doesn't exist.

So either swap the order, and drop the index first:

```
$table->dropIndex('user_id');
$table->dropColumn('user_id');
```

Or just drop the column, and don't worry about the index.

From the MySQL manual:

> If columns are dropped from a table, the columns are also removed from any index of which they are a part. If all columns that make up an index are dropped, the index is dropped as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> To drop an index, you must specify the index's name. By default, Laravel automatically assigns a reasonable name to the indexes. Simply concatenate the table name, the name of the indexed column, and the index type.
>
> Drop a basic index from the "geo" table.
>
> $table->dropIndex('geo_state_index');

Answer (score 0):

From [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#dropping-indexes)

```
$table->dropIndex(['user_id']);
```

To drop an index you need to specify the column's name in `[]`.

And also first you need to drop the index then the column.

```
$table->dropIndex(['user_id']);
$table->dropColumn('user_id');
```